Spark first read from Cloud Storage is very slow on Dataproc Serverless
I'm running a simple Spark job on Dataproc Serverless, and the first step involves reading some CSV files from Cloud Storage in a standard way:
dfOne = spark
.read()
.format("csv")
.load("gs://my-bucket/path-to-my-file/my-file.csv");

I typically need to read several files in sequence (this order is required). The issue I'm facing is that the first file is extremely slow to read—it takes around 15 seconds to load a 45 MB CSV, which seems unusually long. However, subsequent files are read much faster (around 1-2 seconds), even if they are larger than the first file. Interestingly, if I read the first file later in the sequence, it also loads quickly (1-2 seconds). The problem only happens with the very first file. What could be causing this? It seems like some kind of cold start issue, but is there anything I can do to improve this?
My Dataproc Serverless config is 2 executors, each with 4 cores and 12g of memory.

Spark will load libs  such as hadoop on the first start, so this might explain
